# Unicode symbols in raw view on the screen

Tags: javascript, extjs, unicode

trying to read property file with not ASCII symbols by means of javascript namely Ext.i18n.Bundle (https://github.com/elmasse/Ext.i18n.Bundle) and see on the screen the next thing:

\u0427\u0442\u043E \u0442\u043E \u0435\u0441\u0442\u044C \u0442\u0443\u0442

instead of

"Имя Клиента"

Fist my thought was that somewhere I missed UTF-8 encoding, but it is everywhere. If you download the sample by the link, which I mentioned before and change in property file the value to mine you will see the same result.

Can anyone to explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried setting the HTTP Content-Type header on your web server to use 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
?
Actually it's probably sending the properties files as text/plain not text/html but the extra charset directive might help.
http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset

Comment: Yes, I have in my html `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">`